# Drawing a transparent image on an HTML canvas element with JavaScript

Tags: html, image, canvas

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <title>Garage Door Application</title>

    <style>
          body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
          }
          #myCanvas
          {
            //background-color: blue;
          }
          .garagedoorthumbnail:hover
          {
            border: 1px solid green;
          }
    </style>

    </head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="604"></canvas>

    </br>

    <label>Trim Colors</label>
    <select id="trimcolors" name="trimcolors">
        <option>Red</option>
        <option>Green</option>
        <option>Blue</option>
        <option>Yellow</option>
        <option>Purple</option>
     </select>

    <label>House Colors</label>
    <select id="housecolors" name="housecolors">
        <option>Red</option>
        <option>Green</option>
        <option>Blue</option>
        <option>Yellow</option>
        <option>Purple</option>
     </select>

    <div id="doorgallary">
        <img class="garagedoorthumbnail"  src="garagedoor-beadedpanel.png" />
        <img class="garagedoorthumbnail"  src="garagedoor-beadedpanelclassic.png" />
        <img class="garagedoorthumbnail"  src="garagedoor-beadedpaneltrifold.png" />
        <img class="garagedoorthumbnail"  src="garagedoor-beadedpaneltrifoldstockton.png" />
        <p id="drawwhitebackground">White Background<p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageObj = new Image();
        //context.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
        context.globalAlpha = 1;

        imageObj.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        };
        imageObj.src = 'garageblank.png';

        $(".garagedoorthumbnail").click(function() {
            console.log($(this).attr("src"));
            var image = new Image();

            image.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(image, 135, 230, 320, 270);
            };
            image.src = $(this).attr("src");
        });

        $("#drawwhitebackground").click(function() {

            var image = new Image();

            image.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(image, 135, 230, 320, 270);
            };
            image.src = 'garagedoor-whitebackground.png';
        });

        $( "#housecolors" ).change(function() {
            //alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
            var selected = $(this).find(':selected').text();
            console.log(selected);
            if(selected = "Yellow")
            {
                var image = new Image();

                image.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 1000, 604);
                };
                image.src = 'garageblank-yellowhouse.png';      
            }
        });
        $( "#trimcolors" ).change(function() {
            //alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
            var selected = $(this).find(':selected').text();
            console.log(selected);
            if(selected = "Yellow")
            {
                var image = new Image();

                image.onload = function() {
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 1000, 604);
                };
                image.src = 'garageblank-yellowtrim.png';           
            }       
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have been trying to change the values of context.globalAlpha = 1; by changing to context.globalAlpha = 0.1; which does accomplish the goal however everything looks so light that I can not use the canvas. Of course with globalAlpha at 1 the new images I draw on the canvas block out the pixels of the house below so I can not use that either. I'm looking for a happy medium where the canvas image drawn on DOM ready is dark enough and the new images drawn for yellow don't block out the pixels of the house below.

Thank in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply different globalAlpha values as long as you wrap them in context.save and context.restore.

Is that what your asking?

```
context.save();
context.globalAlpha=.5;
context.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0);
context.restore();

context.save();
context.globalAlpha=.1;
context.drawImage(imageObj2, 0, 0);
context.restore();
```

Comment: I'm finding that I can use a background image and set the opacity of the canvas so that when the new images are drawn for yellow they come out very light at globalAlpha = 0.3. For some reason the background image looks like it is now drawn with the 0.3 globalAlpha.

Comment: Cheers! Difficult to diagnose without seeing the images.  Do you know you can drawImage different images with different opacities (globalAlpha)?  Are you drawing your background image at globalAlpha=1.0 and your yellow images at globalAlpha=0.30?  Do any parts of the yellow image overlap the background image such that the background would naturally get softened?

Comment: That's very interesting. Actually I'm going to accept as the answer the post above but a side note what I actually did is use multiple canvases drawn over the top of each other with different globalAlpha values. In this way I was able to accomplish my goal however I am going to have to try this method out to see how it draws a new image with a different globalAlpha. Thank you for posting.